# How to communicate two own Docker container by rabbitmq

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

i am building a very simple project. Two python scripts; `producer.py` and `consumer.py`. Producer sends random numbers, consumer prints it. It's working without docker.

I build two docker images for consumer and producer, and want to "communicate" it by docker-compose, by when i run the docker-compose file i see this:

```
emit_log_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
emit_log_1  |   File "emit_log.py", line 7, in <module>
emit_log_1  |     connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
emit_log_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 359, in __init__
emit_log_1  |     self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
emit_log_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 450, in _create_connection
emit_log_1  |     raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
emit_log_1  | pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError
1_emit_log_1 exited with code 1
```

And exactly the same for receive:

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
 rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq:3-management
  ports:
   - "5672:5672"
   - "15672:15672"


 emit_log:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile.emit_log
  ports:
   - "8081:8081"
   - "8001:8001"
  links:
   - rabbitmq


 receive:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile.receive
  ports:
   - "8082:8082"
   - "8002:8002"
  links:
   - rabbitmq
```

Comment: When you run on local machine you probably connect to RMQ on localhost e.g. `amqp://admin:admin@localhost:5672`, When running in docker (and going by your docker-compose script), the producer, consumer, and RMQ are all in different containers, so you wont be able to use localhost. If you exec into the producer or consumer; can you ping rabbitmq? FYI., docker containers in the same docker network can use container names for DNS resolution e.g. the connection string in producer and consumer would be `amqp://admin:admin@rabbitmq:5672`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may be trying to connect to "localhost" from within your emitting service, which may be pointing to the container localhost itself. Compose will network containers together by default.  If your connection strings were previously on localhost, you will need to update them to point to the desired container.

For instance, if you were previously connecting to `localhost:5672` from your producer or consumer, and they are networked in your docker compose with your rabbitmq instance, you will need to connect using `rabbitmq:5672`

See details about Networking in Compose:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: Yes it's true. I used pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost')). But i have no idea how to do it proper.

Comment: If you're trying to use `pika.ConnectionParameters(host="localhost")` to connect to your RabbitMQ instance running in a separate container, you need to provide the hostname of that container.  Since you're using compose, it will be the name of the service.  So, `pika.ConnectionParameters(host="rabbitmq")`, based on your compose file.  `localhost` worked before you containerized because all three services were presumably running on the same host.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood it. But i still can't solve this problem. I tried host="rabbitmq", rabbitmq:3-management etc. But i have still the same error.